# git locks files for devenv.com build script and causes exceptions like Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: git, visual-studio, locking, devenv

I have a build script which builds a project Web.Auth  inside solution Web.sln via Visual Studio 2015, Powershell and devenv.com:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Devenv.com"  /build Debug /Project  Web.Auth  "C:\Sources\Releases\Web.sln"
```

When we used TFS version control, it worked fine. But after moving to git the problem has appeared with one of 2 errors:

if build single project from command line or rename .git folder and run script

> Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.

project builds but after this error.

or

if build several projects via script and same command

> Attempted to read or write protected memory

If I just simply rename .git folder, and then build - everything becomes ok. 
Via Visual Studio 2015 IDE it builds without problems. Only from console script problem appears.

**How to fix it?**

Rename of *.git* folder by a build script each time doesn't look like a good solution. Remove of index.lock file doesn't help as well as rename of each file inside .git folder. Only whole folder rename partially helps.

Stack for error (Attempted to read or write protected memory):

```
Devenv.com : 
At C:\Sources\Releases\BuildScripts\BuildEnv\buildProjects.ps1:216 char:25
+ ... solResult = & "$VSPath\Devenv.com"  $projectConfigPrefix $buildComman ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Unhandled Exception: 
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at EnvDTE.Commands.Item(Object index, Int32 ID)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.KeyBindingHelper.GetKeyBinding(Guid commandGroup, Int32 commandId, Guid keyBindingScope)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.KeyBindingHelper.GetGlobalKeyBinding(Guid commandGroup, Int32 commandId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Packages.Scc.KeyBindingProvider.GetKeyBinding(Guid commandSet, Int32 commandId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationService.get_PublishKeyBindingText()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationService.InitializeUI()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationService.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, JoinableTaskFactory joinableTaskFactory, CancellationToken cancella
tionToken, ISccDisplayInformationTelemetryLogger telemetryLogger, INotifySolutionLoadCount notifySolutionLoadCount, ITippingInfoProvider tippingInfoProvider, IKeyBindingProvider k
eyBindingProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize.Initialize>b__1(CancellationToken token
)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1.<RunAsyncAsVsTask>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync[T](Func`1 asyncMethod, Boolean synchronouslyBlocking, JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync[T](Func`1 asyncMethod)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.RunAsync[T](JoinableTaskFactory joinableTaskFactory, VsTaskRunContext priority, Func`1 asyncMethod)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.RunAsyncAsVsTask[T](JoinableTaskFactory joinableTaskFactory, VsTaskRunContext priority, Func`2 asyncMethod)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize.Initialize(IAsyncServiceProvider asyncServiceProvider, IProffe
rAsyncService profferAsyncService, IAsyncProgressCallback progressCallback)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackageManagerPrivate.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.<LoadServicePackage>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.LoadServicePackage(Guid guidService, Boolean loadPackageSynchronously)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.<GetAsyncServiceByGuidThrowing>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.GetAsyncServiceByGuidThrowing(Guid serviceGuid, Boolean loadPackageSynchronously)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-OLE-Interop-IServiceProvider-QueryService>b__0>d.MoveNex
t()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider.QueryService>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Th
reading.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(Func`1 asyncMethod, Boolean synchronouslyBlocking, JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Delegate entrypointOverride)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncServiceProvider.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider.QueryService(Guid& guidService, Guid& riid, IntPtr
& ppvObject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider.QueryService(Guid& guidService, Guid& riid, IntPtr& ppvObject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.QueryService(Guid guid, Type serviceType, Boolean setShellErrorInfo, Object& service)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, Boolean setShellErrorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.ServiceProviderExtensionMethods.GetService[T,V](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.SccProviderPackage.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)
```

or:

```
Devenv.com : 
At line:1 char:1
+ & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem when running Fortify scans (a static analysis tool that runs as a plugin to Visual Studio 2017 via the command line) on our build machine. I was getting the same errors as above:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Sure enough, renaming the .git folder fixed the problem. Similarly, we had just moved the solution to a new git repo.

The fix in the end for us was removing following section from the solution file:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 3
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = ...
    ...
EndGlobalSection
```

I also deleted the .vssscc and .vspscc files from the solution. With those changes Fortify was able to scan without error.